# How can images be added to Python Package Index documentation?

Tags: python, setup.py, pypi

I have a module repository that features the module code, a README.md file and images used in the README.md file stored at the directory `images/` (linked to in README.md using relative links). In order to register and upload the module to PyPI, I have the files `setup.py` and `MANIFEST.in`. How should things be such such that the images are included and appear in the PyPI online documentation (as would appear in the hypothetical page https://pypi.python.org/pypi/junkmodule)?

The `MANIFEST.in` and `setup.py` that I have currently (and that do not include images in the PyPI online documentation) are as follows:

## MANIFEST.in

```
include LICENSE
include README.md
include images/*
include setup.py
include junkmodule.py
```

## setup.py

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import os
import setuptools

def main():

    setuptools.setup(
        name             = "junkmodule",
        version          = "0.0.0.1",
        description      = "provides nothing much",
        long_description = Markdown_to_reStructuredText("README.md"),
        url              = "https://github.com/junkuser1/junkmodule",
        author           = "L. Ron. Hubbard",
        author_email     = "lrh@sern.ch",
        license          = "GPLv3",
        py_modules       = ["junkmodule"],
        entry_points     = """
            [console_scripts]
            junkmodule = junkmodule:junkmodule
        """
    )

def read(*paths):
    with open(os.path.join(*paths), "r") as filename:
        return filename.read()

def Markdown_to_reStructuredText(filename):
    try:
        import pypandoc
        return pypandoc.convert(filename, "rst")
    except:
        print("pypandoc not found; long description could be corrupted")
        return read(filename)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 2):

A [possible solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44861847/9817073) is to host the images on GitHub, and then include the images in the README with their explicit URL.

Take for instance this [README](https://github.com/mwouts/jupytext/blob/master/README.md): the logo is included with

```
![](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mwouts/jupytext/master/docs/logo.png)
```

And the logo does appear on [pip](https://pypi.org/project/jupytext/).

Note that you don't even need to host the image in the same GitHub repository - you just need a working URL (an image in another repo, or a gits would work as well).

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While links are great way of sharing knowledge, they won't really answer the question if they get broken in the future. Add to your answer the essential content of the link which answers the question. In case the content is too complex or too big to fit here, describe the general idea of the proposed solution. Remember to always keep a link reference to the original solution's website. See: [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: I see an empty "Screenshots" header on your "this result" page, but I see no images.   Where are the shown images to which you are referring?

Comment: Ah... I see the image reference in your .md file, but the image is no longer available on githubusercontent.com

Answer (score 1):

Use include_pagekage_data and package_data in setup.py file as below.

```
import setuptools

setuptools.setup(name='leofunc',
                 version='1.1.8',
                 description='Leonardo Most Use Functions',
                 url='#',
                 author='leonardo',
                 install_requires=['requests'],
                 include_package_data=True,
                 package_data={'': ['static/*']},
                 author_email='',
                 packages=setuptools.find_packages(),
                 zip_safe=False)
```

Suppose you have LeoFunc package:

```
leo_package
+-- leofunc
    +-- __init__.py
    +-- leo.py
    +-- cfg.py
    +-- static
        +-- avatar.png
+-- setup.py
+-- README.md
```