# Image in README.rst not displaying in pypi

Tags: python, restructuredtext, pypi

I would like an image linked in my README.rst file to be displayed when I upload my package to PyPI.  In my README I have:

```
.. image:: example-python.png
   :height: 100px
   :width: 200px
   :scale: 100 %
   :align: center
```

and in MANIFEST.in I have:

```
# Include the image file
include example-python.png
```

Right now it's not displaying in testpypi.  It shows up just fine on GitHub, however.  Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I'm assuming the image file is not uploaded to PyPI. What does the "longdescription" line of your setup.py look like?

Comment: @Donyor: I have: `setup(... long_description=long_description, ...)` along with `here = path.abspath(path.dirname(__file__))` and 
`with open(path.join(here, 'README.rst'), encoding='utf-8') as f:
    long_description = f.read()`

Answer (score 5):

In `.. image:: example-python.png` you use relative URL, i.e. a browser expects the image in the same directory as the package. I doubt it's possible to upload an image at PyPI. Upload it somewhere and change the URL to be an absolute URL. An image already at Github is ok I think.

`include` directive in MANIFEST.in doesn't work because it includes the image into source (sdist) archive where browsers will never look it up.